# Custom JavaScript Compression in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, compression, minify

I trying to implement my own javascript compression in PHP. Everything works fine except one little thing.

```
private $search = array("   ", " ","new", "return", "var", "function", "\r\n", "\n", "\r");
private $replace = array("", "","new ", "return ", "var ", "function ","", "", "");
private $comments = "/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\)\/\/.*))/";
/*$ctx are the file contents */
$ctx = preg_replace($this->comments, "", $ctx);
$ctx = str_replace($this->search, $this->replace, $ctx);
```

These are the patterns and replaces I have in my code. The only problem I have are the actual strings in javascript. As you can see I have replace the space with "" and when I have a string in JavaScript with space it replaces that as well. for example if I have this string

```
$str = " function(){ return 'This is my name'; } ";
```

the replacing code returns it like this

```
$str = "function (){return 'Thisismyname'}";
```

Is there a regex or another way to fix this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: minifying scripts is more complicated than you seem to think, you should use one of the many compressors available instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, here's one -> https://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: minifiers do not work directly on the code as a string. They do their job on the AST (abstract syntax tree) obtained by parsing the code.

You'll find this talk interesting:
http://gregfranko.com/building-javascript-tools-talk/#1